# Writing out a function to multiply complex numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

I keep running into problems when trying to write code to multiply two complex numbers. I first created a simple class called `Complex`:

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self,real,imag):
        self.real = real   
        self.imag = imag


    def multiply(self, d):
        self.real = (self.real * d.real) - (self.imag * d.imag) 
        self.imag = (self.imag * d.real) + (self.real * d.imag)

    def __str__(self): 
        if self.imag > 0:
            return str(self.real) + " + " + str(self.imag) + "i"
        elif self.imag == 0:
            return str(self.real)
        else:
            return str(self.real) + " - " + str(-self.imag) + "i"
```

Where self.real is the real part and self.imag is the imaginary part. When I run

```
z = Complex(3,4)
x = Complex(2,3)
z.multiply(x)
print(z,x)
```

The result should be `-6 + 17i`, but instead it outputs `-6 - 10i`. What's happening? Is it something to do with the `self.imag`part in the multiply function?

I tried doing it by hand by reading my code, and I got the correct answer. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You modify `self.real` in the first line of your `multiply` method, then use the modified value in the second line. Do both assignments in a single line, i.e.:

```
self.real, self.imag = (self.real * d.real) - (self.imag * d.imag), (self.imag * d.real) + (self.real * d.imag)
```